# How to learn how to solve my own computing problems

Tags: discussion

This site has been very helpful and useful for me over the years. I am usually able to solve whatever problem I am having. But I would like to learn more for myself so I don't always have to come here to ask for help.

My typical problems might be how to install things on Linux system or how to resolve incompatibility issues with software or disable a device etc.. I always get the answer but I usually just follow the instructions without really understanding why I'm typing some random lines at the command prompt or deleting a folder; I solve the problem but don't learn anything.

I don't know where to start learning. Should I just be learning about computer science in general or should I be learning about my operating system? Or something else?

Comment: All operating systems work more or less the same but targeting one in particular will help you get this understanding faster.  Linux is a really good place to learn because you have access to many zealots that would like you to learn how their system works.  I hire people with CS degrees a lot and most of them don't actually understand how a computer works.  This pursuit will probably be one you need to take on personally and not academically. All opinion (of course).. good luck!! :)

Comment: I like SeñorCMasMas' response and I too have witnessed the CS degree people many times lack basic understand of things. The hands-on practical experience is what counts most. There have been times even I re-read something and remember from the IT schooling days that this stuff makes way more sense now. If you are able to go back and study deep after having the hands-on experience, this is where you can really excel understanding things better. Also you could pick something and then just start with the basics 101 of that even if some is repeat and work it up to the advanced subject/components.